# Anyone have problem with HP printer printing only in green?

Tags: 12.10, printing, hp

I just did clean install of Ubuntu 12.10 onto Lenovo i3 desktop.  Single boot, Ubuntu only system.  I have a. HP OfficeJet 6500 network printer.  Drivers seemed to install fine, but libre office only prints text in green.  Same with MS Office 365 online.

Any thoughts?  Probably something simple I accidentally turned on.

Comment: That's probably your printer... Try connecting it to a different computer and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Do a printer self-test, hopefully with color. Does this have only green? Then try a print-driver test page. Same question ..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning the printer heads and checking the ink levels?  I have a HPdeskjet and when the printer heads need cleaning or the ink is low i get a green tinge to everything